# Writing Correlated output to external file in Loadrunner

Tags: loadrunner

I have tried few ways to write my correlated values in a file but didn't succeed. I have correlated student names and they are showing as Student_1 = AAAB...Student_N= A1b2. I can write a count in a file like: Number of students are: # but the individual student names are not writing.
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Could you please edit it in a form of a question that we have enough information to help you solve?

Comment: Dummy scenario: When a student logs on his school website, s/he sees a list of subjects being enrolled in: ACC450, Math300, and Economics. These subjects are student specific. I have correlated the subjects as such when you run it in VuGen, you see the correlated subjects. I need to write those Subjects (i.e. in a file). Sounds easy but my all research has been not successful so far. And yes I am very new and do not work on Loadrunner as of now. This is just for my personal interest. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

As for file writing you can get any C related resource on how to do it, for example this:
http://www.go4expert.com/articles/file-read-write-plain-c-t2977/

You can get the correlated parameter string by lr_eval_string (check the product function reference for details).

Comment: Can you please share the answer ? - from deleted answer by @JagadeeshVenkatesh